# Visual Paradigm - Reverse Engineering - C# Code to Sequence Diagrams

Tags: c#, visual-paradigm

How can we convert C# Code to sequence diagram in Visual Paradigm.

If not, than is there any nuget library which automate the same process in C#.

Comment: We don't ask for libraries here

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Visual Paradigm only support reverse Java source code to sequence diagram.